# Eliminating parameter

Tags: parametric

How do you solve for "$t$" in either equation to eliminate the parameter and solve in terms of $x$ and $y$?
$$
\begin{split}
x&=\frac{ 1+t }{ \sqrt{1+t^2}}\\
\\
y &= \frac{1-t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}
\end{split}
$$

Comment: $x+y = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\cdots}}, x - y = \frac{2t}{\sqrt{\cdots}} \implies t = \frac{x-y}{x+y}$

Comment: Typesetting hint: try enclosing the inside of your square root in braces: `$\sqrt{ ... }$`